# How to POST request for the next software?

Tags: php, post

The software I use has the option to send a request via POST:

```
https://i.gyazo.com/6a5abee28a780e7cec3ca9d6d7cfc7ab.png
```

I want to try it, so I made two PHP files

postform.php:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="post.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="proxies">
<input type="submit" value="Submit Info">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

post.php:

```
<?php
$proxies = $_POST['proxies'];
$file = 'proxies.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $proxies);
?>
```

This should save the result to a txt file afterwards.

It works through the web form, but through the software fails

According to what is written in the software, the request should be sent like this:

```
http://website.com/postform?proxies=%content%
```

What am I supposed to do to make it work?

Comment: you can use  jquery post Method https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Read the software manual coz by seeing % i can tell your "software" is having its own placeholder format

Comment: put the "http://website.com/postform" as form action value and try again?

Comment: use get method in your form

Comment: @Viney You're right, thank you! their code also appears in the manual. https://pastebin.com/uikYgRyj